# General procedure for replacing load-bearing wall with truss on top

Tags: roof, structural, load-bearing, termite, truss

What is a general procedure for replacement of an external load bearing wall wherin the wall is bearing the load of the upstairs floor joists, but also has roof trusts which land directly onto the wall.

I would assume the geral procedure if the trusses weren't there would be to build a temporary wall to support the floor joists and then do the work. However, in this case the trusses also need suppported. The trusses are not anchored in any way to the joists and in most cases there is even an inch or a few inches of seperation from where the joists sit and where the trusses land on the bearing wall.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the situation?

Comment: Yes, I will post a picture tonight.

Comment: Where I live any changes to a load bearing wall have to be done by permit. With multi story structures a engineering stamp is required on the plans to verify the suitability of the new header / support.

Comment: This question specifically addresses a replacement as opposed to a change